# Provision device with JSON/MQTT IOT AGENT FIWARE

Tags: json, mqtt, iot, fiware, fiware-orion

[image]
curl -X POST -vv -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "0000000000000000",
            "entity_name": "BedRoomSensor",
            "entity_type": "multiSensor",
            "attributes": [
                  { "object_id": "t", "name": "Temperature", "type": "celsius" },
                  { "object_id": "h", "name": "Humidity", "type": "degrees" }
            ]
        }
    ]
} 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices'

I execute the above curl commmand in order to provision my device.However it doesn't show anything and the command never ends.
What i missunderstood?
[image: Here are some logs]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem following the first two steps of this guide:http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection-to-the-internet-of-things/how-to-read-measures-captured-from-iot-devices/
In the step-by-step guide these steps weren't described.
In the second step i change the protocol fielde as "MQTT".
Now whenever i request the measures from my device i take the correct value.
[image]